# How to show/hide depending on text input and drop down selection in Html and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to show the government hospitals in bsk when the user enters 560070 and selects government as the choice, but I don't know how to combine the parameters to achieve this. When the user enters 560064 and selects govt/private the hospitals should display respectively.

Here's my code for both separately, but I want to combine them, meaning if both pincode and hospital matches then only it should display.

```js
$(document).on('change', '#pin', function() {
  if ($("#pin").val() == '560070') {
    $("#hiddengovtbsk").show();
    $("#hiddenprivatebsk").hide();
  } else if ($("#pin").val() == '560064') {
    $("#hiddengovtyal").hide();
    $("#hiddengovtyal").show();
  }
});

$('#hospital').on('change', function() {
  if (this.value === "private") {
    $("#hiddenprivatebsk").show();
    $("#hiddengovtbsk").hide();
  } else {
    $("#hiddenprivatebsk").hide();
    $("#hiddengovtbsk").show();
  }
});
```

```css
#hiddenprivatebsk{
    display: none;
    font-size: 5px;
  }
  #hiddengovtbsk{
    display: none;
    font-size: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="pin"> Pincode</label></br>
              <input type="tel" pattern="[1-9][0-9]{5}$" id="pin" name="pin" required=""> 
              <label for="hospital">Hospital:</label>   *</br>
              <select id="hospital" name="hospital" required="">
              <option value="govt">Government</option>
              <option value="private">Private</option></select> 
<div id="hiddengovtbsk">
  <label class="hospitalgovtbsk">
    <input type="radio" name="hospitalgbid" id="hospid" style="vertical-align: left, margin: 0px;" required="">
    Banashankari UPHC, Dobhi Ghat, Government Hospital-Phone:080 
    8799 7765
  </label></br>
  <label class="hospitalgovtbsk">
    <input type="radio" name="hospitalgbid" id="hospid" style="vertical-align: left, margin: 0px;" required="">
    Prathamika Arogya Kendra-Phone:080 2690 9079
  </label></br>
  <label class="hospitalgovtbsk">
    <input type="radio" name="hospitalgbid" id="hospid" style="vertical-align: left, margin: 0px;" required="">
    - Arogya Kendra-Phone:080 8044 7834      
  </label></br>
```

Comment: '*when the user enters 560070 and selects government as the choice*' where is the text being entered in to, and where is this selection being made?

Comment: The text is entered here:<label for="pin"> Pincode</label></br>
              <input type="tel" pattern="[1-9][0-9]{5}$" id="pin" name="pin" required="">

Comment: Please update your code sample with the input textbox so that it is complete. It is difficult to understand it in bits and pieces.

Comment: I have updated the code with the input for pincode

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
var pincodeMatched = false;
var hospitalMatched = false;

$(document).on('change', '#pin', function() {
  if ($("#pin").val() == '560070') {
    pincodeMatched = true;
  } 
showResult();
});

$('#hospital').on('change', function() {
  if (this.value === "private") {
    hospitalMatched = true;
  }
showResult();
});

function showResult(){
    if(pincodeMatched && hospitalMatched){
        //Write you code
    }
    if(pincodeMatched){
        //Write you code
    }
    if(hospitalMatched){
        //Write you code
    }
}
```